# Azure search no longer indexing documents in blob storage

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Up until a couple of weeks ago, I was successfully setting up a data source, index and indexer for documents stored within Azure blob storage. The documents were being indexed as I expected. Now, however, no matter what I do, the same documents are no longer being indexed. I've tried pretty much all possible combinations, re-run the indexer, used different blob storage and even deleted and created a new Azure Search service, but all to no avail. Whenever I run the indexer it just tells me it has been a success with 0/0 documents.

I have no file extension exclusions, only about 20 out of 700 documents have AzureSearch_Skip metadata set to true.

I set up the data source, indexer and index using the default settings in the Azure Search web interface in the Azure portal.

The Azure Search service is called KulaHub if anyone from Microsoft is reading.

Is there an issue with Azure Search for indexing documents in blob storage? I know this question lacks specifics but I wish I could provide more details.

Many thanks

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your indexer batch size got set to 0. Please edit indexer properties in the portal and set the Batch Size to some reasonable number (10 is the default, but if your documents are small, something like 100-500 may be better).

Comment: BTW, we're making a change to make batch size 0 to behave as the default batch size, to avoid such issues in the future.

Comment: Thank you, that has fixed it. However, something must have changed recently because re-creating an indexer in the Azure portal, the batch size defaults to 0 now, which caused this issue.

Comment: It's a regression in our portal blade that we're fixing.