# Azure Search Indexer Succeeded with 0/0 Documents

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

My azure blob indexer was running successfully up until 2-3 days ago for all documents in my storage. However now indexer seems like running successfully but with 0/0 documents. According to [that previously posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572995/azure-search-no-longer-indexing-documents-in-blob-storage) I've set Batch Size property, yet this didn't solve my issue. My indexer settings are:

```
Max failed items: -1
Max failed items per batch: -1
Batch size: 300
```

I have 176 blobs in my storage which have small sizes. Are there any other settings that should be considered in order to run indexer again?

I'm thinking that changing indexer's schedule might have caused to this problem (because it happened after i changed the running schedule frequency to custom) but I'm not so sure since i couldn't find anything to support this..

**EDIT**

After reading [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-reindex#partial-or-incremental-indexing), just to change last modified time, I updated my blob by right clicking -> properties -> save without changing anything. The indexer scanned this updated document but search index duplicated the file. Search Index is showing both previous and updated form of the same document now. I'm totally lost about the logic.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the definition of the index?  Do both copies of the document show the same key value?

Comment: Sorry @BrendanGreen couldn't understand what do you mean by 'definition', what do you want me to provide ? No, updated doc's key starts with 'YQBI..', previous one starts with 'aHR0..'

Comment: Your index will have a `key` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-an-index#field-attributes).  In whatever way you are using the indexer to read the document from blob storage, it appears to be getting a different key - hence you're getting a duplicate of the document inside the index.

Comment: @BrendanGreen yes, that was the problem. I've deleted all the blobs which have 'YQBI..' document key and then created a new index and indexer from scratch. It works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the same Azure Search service "KulaHub" as the linked previously posted question?

Comment: No, I've just checked the question out to have an idea and try whether it'll work for me or not.